# Find how many seconds until a specific time in PHP

Tags: php

I have a variable which contains 600 seconds (10 minutes).

```
$_POST['offerEnd']
```

First I find out what the time will be in 600 seconds

```
$_SESSION['offerEnd'] = date("m/d/Y h:i:s", time() + $_POST['offerEnd']);
```

this gives me:

```
[offerEnd] => 06/30/2017 04:31:19
```

which is wrong, as the time should have been 17:31:19.

Now when i load my page, i want to display how many seconds are left until the $_SESSION['offerEnd'] time.

Im really not sure how to do this, i think ive got it working in my if statement to do something if the time right now is still before the offer end:

```
if (new DateTime() > new DateTime($_SESSION['offerEnd'])) {//do something}
```

But how can i get the amount of seconds left until this offend?

Comment: do `date('H:i:s', $CountdownDate) - date('H:i:s', time())` this should leave you with hours, minutes and seconds left and then convert from there

Comment: this gives me -16?

Comment: how? if you've set `$countdownDate` to be something + 10 minutes - it should be greater than right nows time?

Comment: Ive updated my question, i think im setting my offerEnd wrong

Comment: ah I see right - maybe use `$_SESSION['offerEnd'] = date('m/d/Y H:i:s', strtotime('+'. $_POST['offerEnd'])` `strtotime` is the one you're after - take a look at the PHP documentation for it :) http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: lol, that gives me 01/01/1970 00:00:00

Comment: yeah it will haha I'm not giving full answers I'm giving guides hahaha

Comment: ahhh, i got it:) '+' . $_SESSION['offerEnd'] . ' seconds'

Comment: but still, from this i cannot find how mnay seconds left until this date from your answer above

Comment: still gives -16

Comment: you might need to set your timezone: date_default_timezone_set("MST"); its probably defaulting to UTC

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 `DateTimes` you can use the `getTimeStamp()` method to see how many seconds are left from one to the other.

```
$secondsLeft = (new DateTime($_SESSION['offerEnd']))->getTimeStamp() - 
(new DateTime())->getTimeStamp();
```

You can also construct a DateTime object 600 seconds later with:

```
$_SESSION['offerEnd'] = new DateTime();
$_SESSION['offerEnd']->add(new DateInterval('PT'.$_POST['offerEnd'].'S'));
```